# Excel VBA : How to access (Referenced) Ranges from Formula in a Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell (such as B2 in 'Sheet-1') containing a formula like:

`='Sheet-2'!B2+'Sheet-3'!B3-'Sheet-4'!B4`

Now I want VBA code that can access the references contained in the formula entered in that cell (i.e. B2 in Sheet-1) and then go to those references and make a change in those referred cells.

Comment: The property `Precedents` of a Range will give you these cells. For example: `[B2].Precedents` returns all the cells which are included in the forula in `B2`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on z's comment somewhat.

`Range(<cell>).Precedents` returns a VBA Range representing all cells referred to by `<cell>` e.g. if cell A1 had the formula `=B1+D1` then `Range("A1").Precedents = Range("B1,D1")`

Expanding this to further fulfil the requirements of your question we can then iterate over the cells within this range using a `For Each` loop as shown in the example below:

```
Public Sub AmendPrecedents(fromCell As Range)
    Dim rngReferredTo As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rngReferredTo = fromCell.Precedents

    For Each cell In rngReferredTo
        'Do something with this cell, in this case we're just coloring the background red
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Aiken but when my cell referes to other cells in any other sheets  or other workbooks then this Range(<Cell>).Precedents method returns error as "No cells were found."...